# check whether a textbox value changed in .net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using the following code to check whether the textbox value is changed. The text box value is initially retrieved from the database in a button click event.

Requirement:
I want to update another object(objTest2) property if the tbOffienotes textbox is changed. Further, I want to get only the newly entered text from the text box.

```
If Not tbOfficeNotes.Text.Equals(objTest.OfficeNotes) Then
        Dim strComment As String = tbOfficeNotes.Text.Remove
                                            (0, objTest.OfficeNotes.Length) 
        'Save the test2 object
        objTest2.Comment=strComment

End If
```

Comment: You mentioned only wanting to get the "newly entered text" from yuor text box?  How do you want to handle deleted or modified text?

Comment: I just need to get the newly entered text not the deleted or modified. Anyway it is a useful to know how it can be done. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you store initial value in some control i.e `HiddenField` and compare with current value...if changed then do your operation...

Comment: While this would no doubt work, I believe that nunespascal's answer of subscribing to the TextChanged event of the text box is the more elegant and better solution to the problem.

Comment: @vanattab..Exactly but if you compare it to regards of performance then it's not a good approach indeed. Because this will require a postback everytime even you enter a blank space to compare values if you do it with only asp.net. So better will be to check it once while saving only...

Answer (score 3):

Subscribe to the `TextChanged` event of the textbox. This will be raised when the value changes. You will get the newly entered value in the `Text` property of the textbox

```
Protected Sub tbOfficeNotes_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tbOfficeNotes.TextChanged
     Dim strComment As String = tbOfficeNotes.Text
End Sub
```